# Difference of saving data in the gradle or a class. Android

Tags: android, android-studio, security, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I saw that in some projects the keys and url of the project are saved in a constant, others save it in a gradle.properties and then be called in the build.gradle.
But saving in the build.gradle the key gives some security or what are the benefits of saving data in a class or in the gradle.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Saving the data in gradle file make your URL secure and also you can define different build variants QA, Dev, Live server. You can directly create build by choosing different build variant from option. For more details see below link -

[Build Variant Link](https://blog.mindorks.com/build-variants-in-android)

Comment: How safe? in what way

Comment: URL will be secured and code will be more clean in this way. You can have more information in links https://robosoft.medium.com/configuring-android-builds-a-step-by-step-guide-2e29e2e56487